# NativeScript image size for upload

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My NativeScript Angular app uploads an image to the backend which has a 10MB limit. How can I determine the size of the upload prior to issuing the http POST request? The uploaded image is base64 encoded, as such:

`let imgBase64 = (this.imagesArray.getItem(0).imgsrc).toBase64String("jpeg");`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what tool you are using for uploading your images there are different approaches. The easiest to me seems to use [nativescript-background-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http) plugin. The plugin will cast property change events for currently uploaded, total upload and current status,

For example look at this [POC app](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload) that shows you the progress of the uploaded files in bytes